# how do I get this simple angularjs / springmvc application to work?

Tags: html, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc, angularjs-service

I am trying to create a simple **angularjs/springmvc** "rest" application... -so far, with no success.

In this example, I want to obtain a string value from a spring controller method - i.e., "**getUser()**" and, then, display it on a jsp page - i.e., "**home.jsp**".

after typing "http://localhost:8084/angtest02/home" in the browser, the initial screen displays "user: "...

[image]

Then, when I modify the URL to be "http://localhost:8084/angtest02/home**/user**" - i.e., in order to invoke the spring controller method, the screen still only displays "user: "  (i.e., instead of the desired "**user: Joseph Blow**")...
-- But, additionally, presents a dialog that asks: "*Do you want to open or save user.json (11 bytes) from localhost*"...

[image]

*...Which is NOT what I want.*

Rather, my intention is to have the "**{{user}}**" variable replaced with the value returned by the spring controller method: "**getUser()**".*

*The image, below, is just to illustrate the location of the "{{user}}" variable on the page.*

[image]

***Note***: the spring controller method (i.e., "**getUser()**") is apparently invoked, but, seemingly, not the "**userService**" (i.e., located in app.js)

---

***Below, is my code...***

---

***index.jsp (redirects to home.jsp)***

```
    <%
      response.sendRedirect("home");
    %>
```

***home.jsp***

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>home page</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>    
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>  
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-resource.js"></script>  
            <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/app.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body ng-app="mainApp">
            <div ng-controller="appController">
                <h1>user: {{user}}</h1>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

***app.js***

```
    /* global angular */

    var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

    mainApp.controller('appController', function ($scope, userService) {
        userService.getUser().success(function (data) {
            $scope.user = data;
        });
    });

    mainApp.factory('userService', function ($http) {
        var getUser = function () {
            return $http.get('/home/user');
        };

        return {
            getUser: getUser
        };
    });
```

***UserRestController.java***

```
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    @Controller
    public class UserRestController
    {
        private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger("UserRestController");

        @RequestMapping(value = "/home/user", produces = {"application/json"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<String> getUser()
        {
            LOG.info("_______getUser()_______entering...");

            return new ResponseEntity<>("Joesph Blow", HttpStatus.OK);
        }


        //***seems I need this "init" method, in order to "land" on the "home.jsp" page, initially...
        @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home(HttpSession session)
        {
            LOG.info("_______home()_______entering...");        
            return "home";
        }    
    }
```

FUTHER DETAILS BELOW (IF NEEDED)...

***web.xml***

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
             version="3.1">
        <filter>
            <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
        </listener>    
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml           
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

***project folder structure looks like this***

```
    angtest02
    |
    +-src
        |
        +-main
            |
            +-java
            |   |
            |   +-aaa.bbb.ccc.war
            |       |
            |       +-UserRestController.java
            |
            +-resources
            |   |
            |   +-log4j2.xml
            |
            +-webapp
                |
                +-META-INF
                |   |
                |   +-context.xml
                |
                +-resources
                |   |
                |   +-js
                |       |
                |       +-app.js
                |
                +-WEB-INF
                    |
                    +-spring
                    |   |
                    |   +-applicationContext.xml
                    | 
                    +-views
                        |
                        +-home.jsp
```

***applicationContext.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
                 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
                 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
                 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                 xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
                 xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
                 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
                 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd     
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd     
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd     
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd                                
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core          http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


        <context:component-scan base-package="aaa.bbb.ccc.**" />

        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <context:annotation-config/>

        <tx:annotation-driven/>

        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />        
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>   

        <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />    

    </beans:beans>
```

***pom.xml***

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
        <artifactId>angtest02</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>angtest02</name>
        <properties>
            <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>     
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>     
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.7</version>
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.4</version>
            </dependency>                      
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>ng-grid</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.4</version>
            </dependency>                 
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>    
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                </plugin>            
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Use a @ResponseBody for easier approach like Faraj's answer.

Comment: you are using angular. then why are you mixing it with jsp? It makes me cry a bit

Comment: Hi - I dont really want to use JSP.   (I'm a victim of my environment.)  -Would there be a way that I can leverage spring mvc with non-jsp files? (JSF is not an option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED: The app now seems to be working as I had originally intended...**

[image]

### See changes below...

***home.jsp - changed as follows...(used map object... -unable to use display simple string)...***

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>home page</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>    
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>  
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-resource.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/app.js"></script>        
        </head>
        <body ng-app="mainApp">
            <div ng-controller="appController">
                <h2>test that requests data from rest controller...</h2>
                <p>User: {{user.name}}</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

***app.js - changed as follows...***

```
    /* global angular */

    var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

    mainApp.controller("appController", [ '$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) 
    {
        $http.get('/angtest02/user.json').
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.user = data;
            });
    }]);
```

***UserRestController.java - changed as follows...***

```
    package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

    @Controller
    public class UserRestController
    {
        private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger("UserRestController");

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/xml", "application/json"})
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
        @ResponseBody
        public Map<String, Object> getUser()
        {
            LOG.info("_______getUser_______entering..."); 
            //plain string did not work...    //String user = "Joseph Blow";
            Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("name", "Joseph Blow");

            return user;
        }    

        @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home(HttpSession session)
        {
            LOG.info("_______home_______entering...");         
            return "home";
        }
    }
```

***applicationContext.xml - changed as follows...***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
                 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
                 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
                 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                 xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
                 xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
                 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
                 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd     
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd     
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd     
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd                                
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core          http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


        <context:component-scan base-package="aaa.bbb.ccc.war" />

        <!-- big change here was adding this "contentManager"... -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentManager"/>
        <beans:bean id="contentManager"
              class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
            <beans:property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
            <beans:property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
            <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
                <beans:map>
                    <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                    <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                    <beans:entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                </beans:map>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />        
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>  

        <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />   

    </beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

You controller is trying to produce a json but the format seems to be not a json.

This should solve your issue.

```
@Controller
public class UserRestController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getUser()
    {
        return "Joesph Blow";
    }
    ...
}
```

Or make the controller a RestController

```
@RestController
public class UserRestController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUser()
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Joesph Blow", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks faraj - I'm actually looking for a way to display the value in the "{{user}}" variable on the home.jsp, i.e.,  "<div ng-controller="appController"><h1>user: {{user}}</h1></div>"